# External media handling

Tags: pjsua2

I have a server essentially set up as a B2BUA, and at the start of the call it anchors the media, relaying it between the two parties. At some point I would like to remove the server from the media path and have the two call parties exchange media directly.

I'm hoping I can send a re-INVITE with the SDP that was provided by each of the call parties, but am unable to figure out how to convey the SDP I want to send. Is this even possible, or does PJSUA2 always need to manage the media?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It would be difficult to provide code that isn't a full application. But in general I create an IncomingCall (subclass of pj::Call), and from that initiate an OutgoingCall (also a subclass of pj::Call) using the makeCall() method. The onCallState() and onCallMediaState() callbacks are handled appropriately, and the call is eventually answered with the media flowing between the two calls (startTransmit() is called to feed each call's media to the other).

Comment: At some point in the call (reasons irrelevant) I would like to send re-INVITEs with the SDP that each call originally provided to get them to exchange media directly. There doesn't seem to be a way to provide updated SDP in the reinvite method. Is there another way to do this?